# how to play a wav file from SpeechSynthesizer in MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, media-player

I have some that code (in a WPF application) that when some text is copied to the clipboard it will then read the text out using SpeechSynthesizer (all my code is at the bottom of this post).

However playing the audio this way doesn't allow me to pause, rewind or play etc.

So I thought I would use the SpeechSynthesizer to save a wav file. Then use the MediaPlayer class as it is quite easy to pause, play etc.

However the file does not play in my media player after saving the file. The file is fine and works perfectly when I run it manually. I want to use the MediaPlayer as I have some code already written for it.

**Update**

Using the example [on this page](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-audio/) I can play my wav file. I don't know why the file doesn't run in my code though? In the example above I know they are using a Media Element and have tried that in my code it makes no difference. I am not playing videos only audio hence why I am using the MediaPlayer.

This is all of my current code. The file is being saved but nothing is being played by the media player as far as I can tell, I have the volume up very high on my computer.

```
     using System;
     using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
     using System.Windows.Media;
     using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
     using System.Windows.Interop;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Speech.Synthesis;
     using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
     using System.Windows.Threading;

     namespace CSWPFClipboardViewer
     {
      /// <summary>
      /// Main window of the application, also will be used to get clipboard messages.
      /// </summary>
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
        #region Private fields

        /// <summary>
        /// Next clipboard viewer window 
        /// </summary>
        private IntPtr hWndNextViewer;

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="HwndSource"/> for this window.
        /// </summary>
        private HwndSource hWndSource;

        private bool isViewing;

        private MediaPlayer mePlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Clipboard viewer related methods

        private void InitCBViewer()
        {
            WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            hWndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(wih.Handle);

            hWndSource.AddHook(this.WinProc);   // start processing window messages
            hWndNextViewer = Win32.SetClipboardViewer(hWndSource.Handle);   // set this window as a viewer
            isViewing = true;
        }

        private void CloseCBViewer()
        {
            // remove this window from the clipboard viewer chain
           Win32.ChangeClipboardChain(hWndSource.Handle, hWndNextViewer);

           hWndNextViewer = IntPtr.Zero;
           hWndSource.RemoveHook(this.WinProc);
           pnlContent.Children.Clear();
           isViewing = false;
        }

        private void DrawContent()
        {
           pnlContent.Children.Clear();

           if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
           {
              string path = @"C:\Users\MyPath\";
              string fileName = "MyFile.wav";

              // delete previous file if it exists
              if (File.Exists(path + fileName))
                  File.Delete(path + fileName);

              // we have some text in the clipboard.
              TextBox tb = new TextBox();
              tb.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
              tb.FontSize = 24;
              tb.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
              tb.IsReadOnly = true;
              tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
              pnlContent.Children.Add(tb);

              SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
              synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // 0...100
              synthesizer.Rate = 3;     // -10...10

              //Asynchronous
              synthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile(path + fileName);
              synthesizer.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(synth_SpeakCompleted);
              synthesizer.SpeakAsync(Clipboard.GetText());


             }
            else
            {
               Label lb = new Label();
               lb.Content = "The type of the data in the clipboard is not supported by this sample.";
               pnlContent.Children.Add(lb);
            }
         }

    private IntPtr WinProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                if (wParam == hWndNextViewer)
                {
                    // clipboard viewer chain changed, need to fix it.
                    hWndNextViewer = lParam;
                }
                else if (hWndNextViewer != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // pass the message to the next viewer.
                    Win32.SendMessage(hWndNextViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
                }
                break;

            case Win32.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                // clipboard content changed
                this.DrawContent();
                // pass the message to the next viewer.
                Win32.SendMessage(hWndNextViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Control event handlers

    void synth_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\MyPath\";
        string fileName = "MyFile.wav";

        mePlayer.Open(new Uri(path + fileName));
        mePlayer.Play();
    }

    private void btnSwitch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // switching between start/stop viewing state
        if (!isViewing)
        {
            this.InitCBViewer();
            btnSwitch.Content = "Stop viewer";
        }
        else
        {
            this.CloseCBViewer();
            btnSwitch.Content = "Start viewer";
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CloseCBViewer();
    }

    #endregion
    }
  }
```

**C# Win32**

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace CSWPFClipboardViewer
    {
      /// <summary>
      /// This static class holds the Win32 function declarations and constants needed by
      /// this sample application.
      /// </summary>
      internal static class Win32
      {
         /// <summary>
         /// The WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message notifies a clipboard viewer window that 
         /// the content of the clipboard has changed. 
         /// </summary>
         internal const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x0308;

         /// <summary>
         /// A clipboard viewer window receives the WM_CHANGECBCHAIN message when 
         /// another window is removing itself from the clipboard viewer chain.
         /// </summary>
    internal const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
   }
 }
```

**XAML**

```
 <Window x:Class="CSWPFClipboardViewer.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="Clipboard Viewer" Height="500" Width="640" Background="Black" Closed="Window_Closed">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" Margin="6,0,6,0">Clipboard content:</Label>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="btnSwitch" Width="90" Height="25" Content="Start viewer" Padding="3" Margin="6,6,6,6" Click="btnSwitch_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Width="90" Height="25" Content="Close" Padding="3" Margin="6,6,6,6" Click="btnClose_Click" />
    </StackPanel>

    <DockPanel x:Name="pnlContent" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" Margin="6,6,6,6" LastChildFill="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The file is going to be locked until you explicitly tell SpeechSynthesizer that you're done and won't make any additional Speak/Async() calls.  Either Dispose() the synthesizer or use its SetOutputToNull() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `synthesizer.SpeakAsync` will use the speakers as output. You set the output to a wave file. If you now call `synthesizer.SpeakAsync` the synthesizer will "speak" to the wave file, which in this case means writing to it. So `synthesizer.SpeakAsync` will **not** play any audible sound.

See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavefile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Speech_Synthesis_SpeechSynthesizer_SetOutputToWaveFile_System_String_) for more guidiance.

As soon as the wav file is created you can open it with the media player.

```
synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Youre text goes here");
var pathUri = new Uri(path);
player.Open(pathUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: MediaPlayer mePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mePlayer.Open(path + "MyFile.wav"); I get an error message saying it is expecting a System.Uri not a string

Comment: Wasn't aware of the open signature, Try the updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use SpeakAysnc first? That seems to take away the point of saving the file so it can be used in the mediaplayer class and make use of the pause and play functionality?

Comment: I have updated my post with my latest code. It is not playing anything and I don't know why?

Comment: Have you opened Myfile.wav in an external media player and verified, that the file is created correctly? Besides that, I thought you had already an `MediaPlayer` instance. Why you dont open the file on that instance?

Comment: @mHelpMe : _"I don't understand why you have to use SpeakAysnc first?"_ - If you don't tell it to "speak", how should it output any audio to the file so that you can play it? If you set the output to a .wav file it won't play it through the speakers but instead save the speech into the file (or at least, that's what it's supposed to do).

Comment: @Pretasoc yes I have checked that file has been created correctly. Yes I do have a MediaPLayer instance although it appears to do nothing

Comment: @VisualVincent yes sorry I was being slow there and now understand that

Answer (score 2):

I found something really interesting when I tried to replicate your issue. Surprisingly enough I had the same issue. To debug it I explored MediaPlayer apis and added `MediaFailed` event handler in my code.

To my surprise every time I played something the handler got invoked with following inner exception:
**`MILAVERR_INVALIDWMPVERSION (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980507)`**.

Bit more googling led to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/270a8727-85ba-4b32-a591-c8d41d3e116e/unable-to-play-audio-wave-files-using-wpf-media-element-class-on-windows10?forum=wpf) which states due to anti-competitive government policies in few countries windows 10 is missing common media apps.

To solve this issue you can either make sure you have WMP 10 or greater installed or simply use `SoundPlayer` instead.

```
private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
player.Play();
```